# Assign a JavaScript Function to HTML Input Radiobutton Value

Tags: javascript, html, function, input, radio-button

Is it possible to assign a JavaScript function to html input radiobutton value? I.e.:

---

```
<html>
<input type="radio" name="w_act" class="water_activity" value="tetens(T_op)" ></input>
</html>
<script>
var T_op = 298
function tetens(T_op) {return Math.pow(T_op, -3)} // for clarity :-D
</script>
```

---

The context of my question is that I want to assign the checked input radiobutton value to a variable. It should be either an integer or a function as sketched above.

---

```
<script>
function getData() {
    var act_H2O;
    for (let w_act of document.getElementsByClassName("water_activity")) {
      if (w_act.checked == true){
        act_H2O = w_act.value;
      }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: No, it's not possible. The value is just plain text, it's not executed as JavaScript.

Comment: But there's not reason you can't *set* the radio value with the function either on change of the relevant other element or on document load.

Comment: I was afraid, that it might be senseless. Thanks for clearing it out :-)

Answer (score 1):

Agree with @Barmar , It is not possible what you exactly mean.
But probably other approach could help you that you can assign a JavaScript function to the **onclick** event of the radio button.

here is the code example:

```
label>
  <input type="radio" name="myRadio" value="option1" onclick="myFunction()"> Option 1
</label>
<label>
  <input type="radio" name="myRadio" value="option2" onclick="myFunction()"> Option 2
</label>
```

JS code:

```
function myFunction() {
  // Do something when the radio button is clicked
}
```

I hope this could help!